# Initializing a tokenize group with a number from a configuration in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am able to pass a number to it like so:

```
<split streaming="true"><tokenize token="\n"  group=10")
```

In java dsl its rather easy to pass a variable to group and have the split return chunks of 10 lines.
But the number passed to the group in XML does not seem to work. I tried passing a header value - none of them pass the XSD validation

Does not work:

```
<split streaming="true">
            <tokenize token="\n"  group="${header.linesread}"
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this ? This number is important in order to read large number of lines in one go. 
The processing happens orders of magnitude faster with a large number than with a small number of lines.

Comment: You should be able to use a property to replace the group="${linesread}" in a config file. I don't believe that field is setup to interpret header value at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as Matt commented for Camel 2.19 or older.

But in Camel 2.20 onwards the group value can be dynamic where you can specify the group using the simple language as you do in the *Does not work* section.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 2.18.0. Are there any significant backward compatability issues if we upgrade to 2.18.0 ?